# angular ng-src not working with iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe, widget, servicenow

I am completely new to angular js and am trying to build a google map widget in Service Portal within ServiceNow that dynamically shows the user's job location.  I have a server script that pulls and formats the location:

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('cmn_location');
gr.addQuery('sys_id', gs.getUser().getLocation());
gr.query();
if(gr.next())
{
var loc = gr.street.getHTMLValue();
}

loc1 = loc.replace(/,/g, "");
loc2 = loc1.replace(/ /g, "+");

data.src = loc2;
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class = "map-container">
    <iframe ng-src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCmoLpiJFrdXLLUYsM3PRfPD0zQ0uATAUw&q={{data.src}}'></iframe>
</div>
```

The iframe and {{data.src}} do not work together.  If I take away the iframe portion of the code and replace it with

{{data.src}}

, the address loads correctly.  Also, if I replace {{data.src}} with a real address (i.e. washington+dc), the map shows Washington DC correctly.

Can someone help me troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a simple application that does the same thing and check if the problem is with ng-src or not. Post it here. Then maybe we can also test it out and show a way around for you?

Comment: try this<iframe ng-src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCmoLpiJFrdXLLUYsM3PRfPD0zQ0uATAUw&q=' + {{data.src}}></iframe>

Comment: thanks @MaheshShukla, I tried that without luck either.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function defined in the controller and pass the url to it,

```
 routerApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope,$sce) {
     $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
         return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCmoLpiJFrdXLLUYsM3PRfPD0zQ0uATAUw&q={{data.src}})}}'></iframe>
```

[`demo`](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XnBFFDsOTx8ULFgAj57?p=preview)

Comment: thanks @Sajeetharan!  I tried the code above, but it still doesn't work.